# Всплывающее окно в Visual Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

При написании метода после того как ставлю скобки вылезает такое большое окно (это не окно подсказок, потому что если писать код дальше будет вылазить поверх него окно подсказок) кто знает как его отключить чтоб в последующих таких же действиях оно не появлялось. Заранее благодарю!
[image: Пример ошибки]

Comment: Visual Code никто не пользуется. Здесь найдёшь ответ не скоро, я думаю. Все используют Visual Studio. Visual Studio Community бесплатна. (Там нет этого окошка)

Comment: @user263096, не стоит отвечать если вам нечего сказать.

Comment: Кстати, подсказки то полезные..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам нашел решение проблемы нужно добавить в параметры пользователя строку

```
{
    "editor.parameterHints": false
}
```

после чего перестает всплывать это окно.